# Await within clientscript

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a rest call within a clientscript, the result needs to be applied before the rest of the page js is executed.

How can i achieve this blocking await in a testcafe clientscript?

I get an error when using await as it may not be used at the top level.
There seems to be no way to execute the rest call in testcafe and pass the result into the clientscript.

Comment: If you need to execute a request before the page is loaded, you may not need to execute this request in the context of the page. Instead, you can try to execute it in the [before hook](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402785/reference/test-api/fixture/before).

Comment: the request returns content that needs to be used in the clientscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a promise for this. Just cover every part of the code you want to promise. For example:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const clientFunction = ClientFunction(() => {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => fetch('https://api.kanye.rest/'))
        .then((res) => res.json());
});

fixture`Fixture`;

test('Test', async (t) => {
    const res = await clientFunction();
    console.log(res);
    await t.navigateTo('https://example.com/').debug();
})
```

Alternatively, wrap the call with 'await' with an async function.

```js
//script.js
(async function() {
const resp = await fetch('https://api.kanye.rest/');
const data = await resp.json();
console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} -> Client script executed`);
console.log(data);
})()
```

```js
//test.js
fixture`Fixture`.clientScripts('./script.js').page('https://www.devexpress.com/');
test('Test', async (t) => {
console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} -> Start test`);
await t.debug();
})
```

Comment: the request returns content that needs to be used in the clientscript. your answer only provides the result to the test

Comment: To use data obtained from a request, you can add one more `then` to do everything you require with the result in the ClientFunction context.

Comment: if a clientfunction is used, it is not applied before the rest of the page is executed, this is a key difference to clientscripts. I need to modify a global variable with data from a rest call before the js of the page is executed

Comment: You may not set the start page to fixture and test and navigate to your page after ClientFunction is executed.

When you try to call some function with 'await' in clientScript, you get the expected error: 'await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules'. To avoid it, wrap this call with an async function and run it immediately. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Sadly the async function in your example is not awaited. resulting in code that is executed before the rest but at the same time causing unpredictable results as the code execution is not awaited

Comment: Yeah, you are right. If a request takes a long time, it won't be executed until the page is loaded. `clientScripts` just injects the script at the beginning of the page, but page building isn't blocked by `async` scripts. That's why the first example is definitely better - first an async script is executed, then a page is loaded.